# Port 445 being filtered by Dell Sonicwall

Tags: firewall, azure, port, sonicwall

I need to allow outbound traffic for port 445 in Dell SonicWall firewall to attach a Microsoft Azure remote share.

Because SonicWall support is so lovely when I create a ticket is doesn't even appear as a case so I'm trying here:

Anyone have experience using Dell SonicWall to enable access to Azure Remote Share? Specifically what needs to be done to allow outbound traffic for the port but not inbound?

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vaXA.png)

Comment: Your Portqry result isn't a confirmation that the problem is the SonicWall firewall. Have you verified that port 445 on the host in question is in a listening state? Have you verified connectivity to port 445 from a different network location?

Comment: If you mean the remote host, it's configured directly from Azure dashboard it should already be listening for connections.I guess I can try connecting from off the network via hotspot but I'm guessing it will work.Problem is definitely the firewall.

Comment: You must finish configuration of your IPSEC VPN!

Comment: Have you add port 445 to Azure network security group inbound rules?

Comment: He's using Azure Files, so NSG's are not a factor here. The issue is on the SonicWall side by the looks of it.